# MySQL query using AND, SUM as well as GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Have not had to touch MySQL in 6 years.  Have been thrown back into it to run some report requests.  Here is a working query I have:

```
SELECT colorID, colorName, origColorType, SUM(gallons) AS totalGallons 
FROM netTran2014
WHERE origColorType LIKE '%COMPETITIVE%' 
GROUP BY colorName 
ORDER BY totalGallons DESC;
```

The problem stems in trying to add

```
AND WHERE SUM(gallons) > 0.00
```

I've tried throwing it in there in various ways and get either syntax errors or

> ERROR 1111 (HY000):Invalid use of group function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT colorID, colorName, origColorType, SUM(gallons) AS totalGallons 
FROM netTran2014
WHERE origColorType LIKE '%COMPETITIVE%' 
GROUP BY colorName 
HAVING SUM(gallons) > 0.00
ORDER BY totalGallons DESC;
```

The `HAVING` clause was added to SQL because the `WHERE` keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

Comment: THANK YOU!  "HAVING" was a new one to me - but it will really help me with a lot more of these queries now that I've been thrown back into MySQL!

Comment: I tried to accept your answer at first and was admonished I must wait 10 minutes.  I guess that's in case I feel like something better might come along?

Comment: @BigRedEO: Thats right! You will have to wait for some minutes to accept an answer. Anyway, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

when you add  `SUM(gallons) AS totalGallons`  you create a "fake" column
with such, you need to use "`HAVING totalGallons > XX`" rather then "WHERE"